# lmfit RectangleModel or StepModel

Tags: python, typeerror, lmfit

I am trying to fit the model with peak + background, my code is as below:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import lmfit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate random data 
np.random.seed(1234)
y_data = np.random.normal(loc =5, scale = 4, size=100000) + np.random.exponential(scale = 5, size=100000)
# Histogram the data for fitting
y, x = np.histogram(y_data, bins=100, density=False)
# # # calculate bin centers
x=(x[1:]+x[:-1])/2
# plt.plot(x,y)
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=stats.sem(y), fmt='.', zorder=1, label='data points')

peak1 = lmfit.models.SkewedVoigtModel(prefix="peak_")
pars = peak1.make_params()
# Set some parameters
pars['peak_center'].set(value=5, vary =True)
pars['peak_sigma'].set(value=4,vary=True)
# Set the background
#background1 = lmfit.models.PolynomialModel(3,prefix="back_",)
background1 = lmfit.models.RectangleModel(prefix="back_", format='arctan')
pars.update(background1.guess(y, x=x)) 
# Make full model to fit
model = peak1 + background1
# Fit our full model
out = model.fit(y, pars, x=x)
# Make a more fine set of x's to plot with
xs= np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100)
 # Plot our output model withe the new parameter and finer x's
plt.plot(xs, out.eval(params=out.params, x=xs), label='Total Fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This code produce error:
TypeError: lmfit.parameter.Parameter.set() argument after ** must be a mapping, not numpy.int64

This is indicating this line is responsible for the error:  pars.update(background1.guess(y, x=x)
It will not produce eror if I use PlynomialModel or other type models. StepModel and RectangleModel has this issue. My numpy version is 1.2.0 which has RectagleModel included. Any suggestions, how to resolve the issue?

I tried changing the models it worked (see pic attached) but not working with rectanglemodel.
[image]

Comment: Your code is not formatted properly and cannot run.  When you report an error, give the full traceback and unedited message -- it is not even clear which like is causing the error.  But also: do not expect `Model.guess` to work flawlessly or without checking the results.   You may very well need to alter those guessed  values to get a suitable fit.

Comment: Thanks, M Newville, I just edited the code so you can see what I am struggling with. It was working correctly a few months back but I had updated numpy, matplotlib in between. It should be related to that, but I don't have a deeper knowledge of how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for updating the code and sorry for the trouble.  I believe this reveals a bug in `lmfit` that should be raised as an Issue on Github and fixed.   The issue seems to be that values of type `np.Int64` are not currently recognized (in lmfit 1.2.0, due to changes introduced for that version, by me;)) correctly.  I think a fix in the code is simple.

For a quick workaround, I believe that doing

```
pars.update(background1.guess(y*1.0, x=x*1.0))
```

in your script should work correctly.   To be clear, that should not be necessary, but it will avoid this current bug.

Comment: Thanks, That worked as you suggested!